# jquery selector with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

How to select li in repeated ul with same class at click event

```
<div id="holder">

  <ul class="pattern">
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pattern">
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>
     <li>6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pattern">
     <li>7</li>
     <li>8</li>
     <li>9</li>
     <li>10</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

i want to select/get the li with number 5(ex only), pls assume that i have a bunch of ul with same classes.

since i have a lot of ul, im looking for selecting the index of ul then select the li.

Comment: pls check my answer it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.pattern li').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).index())
  console.log($(this).text())
  console.log($('.pattern').find('li:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').text())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">

  <ul class="pattern">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pattern">
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pattern">
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Try this way

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's `:contains` selector:

```
 $("li:contains('5')")
```

For example:

```js
$("ul.pattern").click(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  console.log(index);
  $("ul.pattern").eq(index).find("li:contains('5')").css("background","red");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">

  <ul class="pattern">
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pattern">
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>
     <li>6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pattern">
     <li>7</li>
     <li>8</li>
     <li>9</li>
     <li>10</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

**Edit:** Code updated to get current index of currently clicked `ul` using `index()` and locating the specific `li` among all `ul`'s with the text `5` by using `eq()` and `find()` (with the `:contains` selector)

Comment: actually i dont have any content in my li, my scenario is, when li is click (  get the dom position and return something .html("blablabla") )

Comment: I suppose you may need to modify your question to include your requirement.

Comment: Not sure about your specific use-case but see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$('<li>').val() == 5;
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.